# What's the appropiate pronoun for a program named after a woman?

Tags: pronouns, software, feminine

In a technical document introducing an operating system named after a famous woman, I have to refer to the OS itself. I've consistently used "it/its" but some sentences sound a little weird.

Is it grammatically correct to occasionally use "her" instead of "its"?

Comment: There's [an eel virus called EVE](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=zrn8QVr48iAC&pg=PT149&lpg=PT149&dq=virus+called+eve&source=bl&ots=4qPl9pFkq0&sig=ls5pNfmqsFsUo3LNP3WqAsVtfe0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjKrfrE0snQAhVpBsAKHWcRDtQQ6AEINDAE#v=onepage&q=virus%20called%20eve&f=false), but you wouldn't say ***she's** species-specific*.

Comment: As an aside, *program* is a count noun, but *software* is non-count.

Comment: You don't refer to the programming language Pascal as *him*, do you? Stick to *it*.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Her_(film) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_personal_assistant

Comment: As mentioned by @Robusto, "It" is appropriate. In the Wikipedia article on [ADA language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_(programming_language)), it is written "Because of Ada's safety-critical support features, it is now used not only for military applications" or " It is also used in the French TVM in-cab signalling system on the TGV high-speed rail system, ...".

Comment: If you're talking about Ada, I've never heard it referred to as anything but "it".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We generally don't refer to software programs using *he* or *she*. Even if named after a man or woman, a software program is still an inanimate object, so we should just use *it*.

Comment: Possible exception to your implied ("inanimate object") rule: ["feminine pronouns are sometimes used when referring to ships (and more uncommonly some airplanes and analogous machinery)"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_in_English)

Comment: @Keepthesemind - And the feminine pronoun would still tend to be used if the boat is the *John Smith*.

Comment: @HotLicks Here [she](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:John_Smith_(ship)) is. Unrelatedly, it seems that vessels just have (complete) names, not first, last names.